# Do both functions need to be Async when being called or just the parent function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have two functions and the parent function (function Two) is marked as async and uses the await keyword when calling One, will the code inside function One() run async or do both functions need to be marked as async.

```
function One(){
  // Asynchronous Code
}

async function Two(){
  await One();
}
```

Comment: Using the keyword `async` doesn't automatically make a function asynchronous. You have to write asynchronous code. `async` just makes the function return a promise if it doesn't already return a promise and it allows to use `await`.

Comment: That was implied but I should've been more clear, edited my question.

Comment: Please add more context/example on what you are trying to do so we can have more clear vision what you are trying to achieve [mre]

Comment: _"will the code inside function One() run async or do both functions need to be marked as async"_ Asynchronous code will always run asynchronousls unrelated if the functions are marked as `async`

Comment: I'd rather delete the question. I found out what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the function `One()` returns a promise, you can `await` its return value. So you don't *necessarily* need to mark One() as async.

For example:

```js
function One() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 42))
}

async function Two(){
  console.log("Calling One()...")
  let ret = await One();
  console.log("One() returned:", ret)
}

Two()
```

Answer (score 5):

The function that uses `await` must be `async`.

The value that you `await` needs to be a Promise (or the `await` is pointless).

Functions marked as `async` always return Promises, but that's only a useful way to create a Promise if you are using `await` inside it.